# Android Wi-Fi Direct for ad-hoc multiplayer games

Tags: android, multiplayer, wifi-direct

Android v4.x devices, such as the Samsung Galaxy Nexus or S3, support Wi-Fi Direct. I'm thinking about creating a game that players who are all located in one room can play. Since the game requires a central point for consistency management of game state, I'm thinking about using the client/server architecture after all. That means:

- Player A starts the game and decides to host a server -> his screen then shows a lobby where he can see other devices/players who have decided to join the game (it could e.g. allow chatting, and it allows A to trigger the start of the game session)
- Other players (B, C, D...) start the the game, decide to join an existing game. They should see A's game (while it is still in lobby-state) and join the game.

Now, since I don't have several 4.0 devices available yet (otherwise I'd simply try myself), I'm wondering how the [Android Wi-Fi Direct APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html) will work in practice. For example, I'm unclear about

1. the interplay of what A needs to do in the Android-OS Wi-Fi settings dialog, and what can be done from within the game application
2. Like 1, but for players B, C, etc.: do they need to use the WiFi-Settings dialog first to do a pairing with the server? Or can that all be solved from within the game application using the APIs?
3. How do the APIs need to be used to make sure that B, C actually only see A's game, and not other devices?
4. The point of time at which a device actually "discoverable" (who/what action decides about this?)

Cheers!

Comment: hey I also have the same issue....any solutions you got...If yes that vll b a great help... thanks in advance....